# Получение температуры батареи на android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sdk

Я создаю приложение, которое показывают температуру батареи. Мне надо получить текущую температуру батареи. Как это сделать? Я нашёл только получение температуры окружающей среды. Как должна выглядеть моя функция?

```
fun getBatteryTemp(){
    val temp = ...
    return temp
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383581/how-get-battery-temperature-with-decimal вот например

Comment: Кажется это работает, у меня нет возможности пока проверить на настоящем телефоне, а на эмуляторе нормально. Я проверю в течение 2 часов

Comment: рад что у вас получилось решить вашу проблему :)